# Android: onTouchListener - cancel touch event when user moves touch outside of view

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener

We've all done it, when we hold down on a button we're not sure we want to click or not, and while holding down on the screen still, we move our finger so the touch event doesn't fire.

I'd like to mimic this behavior with my onTouchListener. I have a list of cards. Every card has an onTouchListener that fires an Intent on touch event UP. If the user moves the finger off of the card while still holding down on the screen, I'd like to make sure that intent is not fired.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            if (event.getX() < width && event.getY() < height) {
                //finger is on the card and fire intent
            }
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, and it looks promising. As for 'width' and 'height',  are these built into the onTouchListener, or do I have to define those myself?

Comment: no you can get those values with `view.getWidth()`/`view.getHeight()` @JoshBeckwith

Comment: So I gave it a shot, and it was working as intended. However, I found a more simple solution when doing more research on your answer.

There is actually a MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE which does exactly the same thing. Just thought I'd let you know.

Edit: I've switched from MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE to MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL so that I can properly take care of resetting my views color properties. They work very similar.